# Retaining a variable's value after re-calling a function

Tags: python, variables, tkinter, game-engine, python-3.3

i have been trying to fix this for a while now, but i cannot seem to make it work properly. I am trying to make a game of pong with python and trying to make it best out of three games. However, i am running into trouble when I restart the game after each round, I cant find a way to keep the value of the wins1 and wins2 variables. I have them set to 0 at the start and i know that this doesn't retain the value, as it resets back to 0 every time the pongyay() function is called, but I am keeping it there so as to not get any other errors. If anyone could give a good suggestion on how to retain the vaules of these, but still keep them in the loop that i have running the game, it would be much appreciated. Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import time
import subprocess
import sys

tk = Tk()
tk.title("Epic Game of Destiny") # Title of the window
tk.resizable(0, 0)
tk.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
wins1 = 0
wins2 = 0

def pongyay():

    canvas = Canvas(tk, width=700, height=400, bd=0, highlightthickness=0) #canvas attributes
    canvas.configure(background='black')
    canvas.pack()
    tk.update()

    class Rectangle:
        def __init__(self, canvas, color):
            self.canvas = canvas
            self.paddle = paddle
            self.paddle2 = paddle2
            self.id = self.canvas.create_rectangle(6, 20, 0, 0, fill=color)

    class Brik:
        def __init__(self, canvas, color):
            self.canvas = canvas
            self.paddle = paddle
            self.paddle2 = paddle2
            self.id = self.canvas.create_rectangle(6, 30, 0, 0, fill=color)

    class PowerUp: #class that creates the ball and assigns its attributes
        def __init__(self, canvas, color):
            self.canvas = canvas
            self.paddle = paddle
            self.paddle2 = paddle2
            self.id = canvas.create_rectangle(10, 10, 10, 10, fill=color) #attributes, using self.id, which allows the detection of the current object self.id is
            self.canvas.move(self.id, 400, 400) #starting position

        def draw(self): #how the powerup bounces and reacts to its surroundings
            self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, self.y)
            pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
            if pos[1] <= 0:
                self.y = 2
            if self.hit_paddle(pos) == True:
                canvas.move(self.id, 1000, 1000)
            if self.hit_paddle2(pos) == True:
                canvas.move(self.id, 1000, 1000)
            if pos[3] >= self.canvas_height: #places the powerup on the canvas and detects where the edges are, meaning that when the powerup hits the edge it will bounce off
                self.y = -2
            if pos[0] <= 0:
                self.x = 2

    class Ball: #class that creates the ball and assigns its attributes
        def __init__(self, canvas, color):
            self.canvas = canvas
            self.paddle = paddle
            self.paddle2 = paddle2
            self.id = canvas.create_rectangle(10, 10, 25, 25, fill=color) #ball attributes, using self.id, which allows the detection of the current object self.id is
            self.canvas.move(self.id, 330, 200)
            starts = [-2, 2]
            start2 = [-1, 1]
            random.shuffle(starts)
            random.shuffle(start2)#ball starting position
            self.x = starts[0]
            self.y = start2[0]
            self.canvas_height = self.canvas.winfo_height() #gets size of canvas in order to allow ball to bounce off the walls
            self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
            self.side1 = False
            self.side2 = False

        def hit_paddle(self, pos):
            paddle_pos = self.canvas.coords(self.paddle.id)
            if pos[2] >= paddle_pos[0] and pos[0] <= paddle_pos[2]: # returns true or false when the ball does or does not hit the paddle, which then allows the ball to bounce off it
                if pos[3] >= paddle_pos[1] and pos[3] <= paddle_pos[3]:
                    return True
            return False

        def hit_paddle2(self, pos):
            paddle2_pos = self.canvas.coords(self.paddle2.id)
            if pos[2] >= paddle2_pos[0] and pos[0] <= paddle2_pos[2]: # returns true or false when the ball does or does not hit the paddle, which then allows the ball to bounce off it
                if pos[3] >= paddle2_pos[1] and pos[3] <= paddle2_pos[3]:
                    return True
            return False

        def draw(self): #how the ball bounces and reacts to its surroundings
            self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, self.y)
            pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
            if pos[1] <= 0:
                self.y = 8
            if self.hit_paddle(pos) == True:
                self.x = -8
            if self.hit_paddle2(pos) == True:
                self.x = 8
            if pos[3] >= self.canvas_height: #places the ball on the canvas and detects where the edges are, meaning that when the ball hits the edge it will bounce off
                self.y = -8
            if pos[0] <= 0:
                self.side1 = True
                self.x = 8
            if pos[2] >= 700:
                self.side2 = True
                self.x = -8
            if pos[0] >= 1:
                self.side1 = False
            if pos[2] <= 700:
                self.side2 = False


    class Paddle: #class to create the paddle and its attributes
        def __init__(self, canvas, color):
            self.canvas = canvas
            self.id = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 15, 80, fill = color) #the paddles attributes, it is long and thin, and will be filled with the color specified
            self.canvas.move(self.id, 50, 200)
            self.y = 0
            self.canvas_height = self.canvas.winfo_height()
            self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Up>', self.turn_left) # keybindings that moves the paddle along the canvas
            self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Down>', self.turn_right)
            self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyRelease-Up>', self.stop_left) # keybindings that moves the paddle along the canvas
            self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyRelease-Down>', self.stop_right)

        def turn_left(self, evt):# when the left key is pressed, the paddle moves along at this speed
            self.y = -9

        def turn_right(self, evt): # when the right key is pressed, the paddle moves along at this speed
            self.y = 9

        def stop_left(self, evt):# when the left key is released, the paddle will stop moving
            self.y = 0

        def stop_right(self, evt): # when the right key is released, the paddle will stop moving
            self.y = 0

        def draw(self):
            pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id) #this detects the side of the canvas and stops the paddle from moving past it
            if pos[1] <= 0:
                self.y = 1
            elif pos[3] >= self.canvas_height:
                self.y = -1
            self.canvas.move(self.id, 0, self.y)

    class Paddle2: #class to create the paddle and its attributes
        def __init__(self, canvas, color):
            self.canvas = canvas
            self.id = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 15, 80, fill = color) #the paddles attributes, it is long and thin, and will be filled with the color specified
            self.canvas.move(self.id, 50, 200)
            self.y = 0
            self.canvas_height = self.canvas.winfo_height()
            self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-a>', self.turn_left2) # keybindings that moves the paddle along the canvas
            self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-z>', self.turn_right2)
            self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyRelease-a>', self.stop_left2) # keybindings that moves the paddle along the canvas
            self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyRelease-z>', self.stop_right2)


        def turn_left2(self, evt):# when the left key is pressed, the paddle moves along at this speed
            self.y = -9

        def turn_right2(self, evt): # when the right key is pressed, the paddle moves along at this speed
            self.y = 9

        def stop_left2(self, evt):# when the left key is released, the paddle will stop moving
            self.y = 0

        def stop_right2(self, evt): # when the right key is released, the paddle will stop moving
            self.y = 0

        def draw(self):
            pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id) #this detects the side of the canvas and stops the paddle from moving past it
            if pos[1] <= 0:
                self.y = 1
            elif pos[3] >= self.canvas_height:
                self.y = -1
            self.canvas.move(self.id, 0, self.y)

    paddle = Paddle(canvas, 'white') #the object of the paddle that will be instantiated
    paddle2 = Paddle2(canvas, 'white')
    ball = Ball(canvas, 'white') #the object of the ball that will be instantiated
    powerup = PowerUp(canvas, 'white')

    paddle.draw()
    paddle2.draw()

    brick1 = Brik(canvas, 'white')
    brick5 = Brik(canvas, 'white')
    brick1.canvas.move(brick1.id, 450, 200)
    brick5.canvas.move(brick5.id, 250, 200)
    rectangle1 = Rectangle(canvas, 'white')
    rectangle2 = Rectangle(canvas, 'white')
    rectangle3 = Rectangle(canvas, 'white')
    rectangle4 = Rectangle(canvas, 'white')
    rectangle5 = Rectangle(canvas, 'white')
    rectangle6 = Rectangle(canvas, 'white')
    rectangle7 = Rectangle(canvas, 'white')
    rectangle8 = Rectangle(canvas, 'white')
    rectangle9 = Rectangle(canvas, 'white')
    rectangle10 = Rectangle(canvas, 'white')
    rectangle11 = Rectangle(canvas, 'white')
    rectangle1.canvas.move(rectangle1.id, 350, 380)
    rectangle2.canvas.move(rectangle2.id, 350, 342)
    rectangle3.canvas.move(rectangle3.id, 350, 304)
    rectangle4.canvas.move(rectangle4.id, 350, 266)
    rectangle5.canvas.move(rectangle5.id, 350, 228)
    rectangle6.canvas.move(rectangle6.id, 350, 190)
    rectangle7.canvas.move(rectangle7.id, 350, 152)
    rectangle8.canvas.move(rectangle8.id, 350, 114)
    rectangle9.canvas.move(rectangle9.id, 350, 76)
    rectangle10.canvas.move(rectangle10.id, 350, 38)
    rectangle11.canvas.move(rectangle11.id, 350, 0)
    paddle2.canvas.move(paddle.id, 583, 0)
    tk.update_idletasks
    tk.update()

    global score1
    global score2
    score1 = 0
    score2 = 0

    def restart():
        result = messagebox.askyesno("Revenge?","Would you like to restart?")
        if result == True:
            score1 = 0
            score2 = 0
            canvas.destroy()
            pongyay()           
        else:
            tk.destroy()

    while 1:
        tk.update_idletasks() #loop that and allows it to move, by updating tkinter every 0.01 second
        tk.update()
        time.sleep(0.0000001)
        ball.draw()
        paddle.draw()
        paddle2.draw()


        if ball.side1 == True:
            score2 = score2 + 1
            print(score2)
            if score2 == 1:
                rc1 = canvas.create_rectangle(5, 5, 15, 15, fill='white')
                canvas.move(rc1, 365, 20)
            if score2 == 2:
                rc2 = canvas.create_rectangle(5, 5, 15, 15, fill='white')
                canvas.move(rc2, 385, 20)
            if score2 == 3:
                rc3 = canvas.create_rectangle(5, 5, 15, 15, fill='white')
                canvas.move(rc3, 405, 20)
            if score2 == 4:
                rc4 = canvas.create_rectangle(5, 5, 15, 15, fill='white')
                canvas.move(rc4, 425, 20)
            if score2 == 5:
                rc5 = canvas.create_rectangle(5, 5, 15, 15, fill='white')
                canvas.move(rc5, 445, 20)
            if score2 == 6:
                rc6 = canvas.create_rectangle(5, 5, 15, 15, fill='white')
                canvas.move(rc6, 465, 20)
            if score2 == 7:
                rc7 = canvas.create_rectangle(5, 5, 15, 15, fill='white')
                canvas.move(rc7, 485, 20)
            if score2 == 8:
                rc8 = canvas.create_rectangle(5, 5, 15, 15, fill='white')
                canvas.move(rc8, 505, 20)
            if score2 == 9:
                rc9 = canvas.create_rectangle(5, 5, 15, 15, fill='white')
                canvas.move(rc9, 525, 20)
            if score2 == 10:
                rc10 = canvas.create_rectangle(5, 5, 15, 15, fill='white')
                canvas.move(rc10, 545, 20)


        elif ball.side2 == True:
            score1 = score1 + 1
            print(score1)
            if score1 == 1:
                rc1 = canvas.create_rectangle(5, 5, 15, 15, fill='white')
                canvas.move(rc1, 320, 20)
            if score1 == 2:
                rc2 = canvas.create_rectangle(5, 5, 15, 15, fill='white')
                canvas.move(rc2, 300, 20)
            if score1 == 3:
                rc3 = canvas.create_rectangle(5, 5, 15, 15, fill='white')
                canvas.move(rc3, 280, 20)
            if score1 == 4:
                rc4 = canvas.create_rectangle(5, 5, 15, 15, fill='white')
                canvas.move(rc4, 260, 20)
            if score1 == 5:
                rc5 = canvas.create_rectangle(5, 5, 15, 15, fill='white')
                canvas.move(rc5, 240, 20)
            if score1 == 6:
                rc6 = canvas.create_rectangle(5, 5, 15, 15, fill='white')
                canvas.move(rc6, 220, 20)
            if score1 == 7:
                rc7 = canvas.create_rectangle(5, 5, 15, 15, fill='white')
                canvas.move(rc7, 200, 20)
            if score1 == 8:
                rc8 = canvas.create_rectangle(5, 5, 15, 15, fill='white')
                canvas.move(rc8, 180, 20)
            if score1 == 9:
                rc9 = canvas.create_rectangle(5, 5, 15, 15, fill='white')
                canvas.move(rc9, 160, 20)
            if score1 == 10:
                rc10 = canvas.create_rectangle(5, 5, 15, 15, fill='white')
                canvas.move(rc10, 140, 20)


        if score1 == 10:
            wins1 = 0
            wins1 = wins1 + 1
            print(wins1)
            time.sleep(2)
            score1 = 0
            score2 = 0
            canvas.destroy()
            pongyay()
            if wins1 == 1:
                finalpoint = Label(tk, text='This Match Decides The Winner', fg="white", bg="black", font=("OCR A Std", 50))
                finalpoint.pack()
                finalpoint.place(x = 350, y = 200)
                time.sleep(1.5)
                finalpoint.destroy()
            if wins1 == 2:
                finalpoint1 = Label(tk, text='Player 1 Wins!', fg="white", bg="black", font=("OCR A Std", 50))
                finalpoint1.pack()
                finalpoint1.place(x = 350, y = 200)
                restart()

        if score2 == 10:
            wins2 = 0
            wins2 = wins2 + 1
            print(wins2)
            time.sleep(2)
            score1 = 0
            score2 = 0
            canvas.destroy()
            pongyay()
            if wins2 == 1:
                finalpoint = Label(tk, text='This Match Decides The Winner', fg="white", bg="black", font=("OCR A Std", 50))
                finalpoint.pack()
                finalpoint.place(x = 350, y = 200)
                time.sleep(1.5)
                finalpoint.destroy()
            if wins2 == 2:
                finalpoint2 = Label(tk, text='Player 2 Wins!', fg="white", bg="black", font=("OCR A Std", 50))
                finalpoint2.pack()
                finalpoint2.place(x = 350, y = 200)
                restart()


pongyay()
```

The main area that the problem is occuring is at the bottom with the scoring.

Thanks again to anyone who answers

Comment: Why do you have a different class for each paddle?

Comment: I found it easier to test the two paddles apart from each other and when i build on the game, the two paddles will end up having different attributes

Comment: Their behavior is nearly identical. Most of their methods are the exact same. It'd make sense to have one class and just pass the things that need to be different into the constructor, or have a base class implementing the common functionality and have the subclasses just do the parts that have to be different.

Comment: thanks very much for your help, I will implement that after i find a way to fix the scoring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at these two bits:

```
            wins1 = 0
            wins1 = wins1 + 1
```

and

```
            wins2 = 0
            wins2 = wins2 + 1
```

You're wiping the win counts before you increment them. If you want to initialize the win counts, do it outside the loop.

Near the top of your code, you create a pair of global `wins1` and `wins2` variables; perhaps you meant to use those inside `pongyay`?

```
tk.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
wins1 = 0
wins2 = 0
```

If so, remove the `wins1 = 0` and `wins2 = 0` lines from inside `pongyay`, and declare `global wins1` and `global wins2` inside `pongyay` so the function uses the global variables instead of creating local variables.

Comment: I know that I wipe the win counts, but that is only there to stop more errors from occuring, but when i put the win count code outside the loop, it ends up not doing anything

Comment: If you look at the code you can see that the if statement destroys the canvas and re-calls the pongyay() function, even if i put them outside the loop, it will just set to 0 every time

Comment: @user2992997: "only there to stop more errors from occuring" - do you know why the other errors were occuring or why wiping the win counts stopped those errors? Wiping the win counts isn't a fix; you'll need to figure out what went wrong when the win count initialization was outside the loop and fix it properly. I suspect issues with the scope of your variables.

Comment: I have done what you have said and put the win counts out side the loop, however it still wipes them because of the re-calling of the pongyay() function, all i was asking was if people knew how to get around that

Comment: Don't restart by calling the function again. That's a common attempt to implement restart functionality, but it's broken. Instead, wrap the code that needs to restart in a loop and direct the control flow of your program to the next loop iteration. You may be able to use your existing main loop for this purpose by resetting the things that need to reset when a round ends.

Comment: Sorry, i really dont understand, how do i use a loop to re run the classes?

Comment: I don't think I'm sufficiently awake at this point to explain that. I need to go to bed soon. I've expanded my answer a bit, though; adding the `global` declarations and removing the win-wiping lines from `pongyay` should theoretically patch up the immediate problem.